# Std::string to std::array?

Tags: c++, c++11

What's the recommended way to convert a string to an array? I'm looking for something like:

```
template<class T, size_t N, class V>
std::array<T, N> to_array(const V& v)
{
    assert(v.size() == N);
    std::array<T, N> d;
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), d.data());
    return d;
}
```

Does C++11 or Boost provide something like this? How do others do this? Seems silly having to copy/paste this function myself every time I need it in a project.

Comment: Erm, put it in a header?

Comment: I've got a map with about 1 million 20 (or 32) byte keys and I'd like to avoid the extra allocations and indirections required by std::string

Comment: std::string is as efficient, as std::vector - did you profile and saw there is a problem?

Comment: This is about std::array, not std::vector.

Comment: It just doesn't look that useful; if you know that your data is 20 or 32 bytes long at compile time, why are you passing it through a string?

Comment: If your string lengths are not fixed size (below 32 bytes) you might want to add null after the last character in the array, ie, d[v.size()] = 0;

Comment: @ViktorSehr `d[v.size()]` is an out of bounds access. The strings have the exact size, there's an assertion documenting that.

Comment: @Joe: It's database/user input, so I have to copy it into an array at some point.

Comment: @Martinho: No, it's not. He said: if (v.size() < d.size()) d[v.size] = 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That seems fine. There isn't such a thing in C++11, and I don't think there is one in Boost either. If you don't want to paste this all over the place, you can just put it in a header and `#include` that.

Comment: Copying a header is a bit better than copying the function, but still not ideal for something as basic as constructing an array.

Comment: You need this in *every* project? It strikes me as something that has a specific niche use. And that's exactly why you don't find it in C++11 or boost: it's not really a basic thing.

Comment: Typically, when you have a series of projects in a company, you put them in one phsical directory hierarchy with common libraries.  Professionals don't copy the files from boost they want to use to every project using them; they have one copy of boost and use it from the same location across their projects.  Similarly, if you have a utility library header with this function in it, you don't copy it to each project, you use the one header in a special location.  This way, if you have to fix a function or update, you don't deal with divergence of code and bugfix multiple times.

Comment: That's fine for multiple projects in a company, but not for unrelated projects, not in a company.

Comment: @XTF : Why would two unrelated projects need this same piece of nearly-pointless code?

Comment: @Martinho: No, but it seemed like such a basic feature. Containers like list and vector do support simple construction from an iterator pair. I can't imagine me being the only one that uses this.

Comment: @XTF: "but not for unrelated projects, not in a company." Everyone, even for personal projects, has their own little library of utility and convenience functions. This isn't a hard thing to do. Just have a directory with a project for this stuff. No need for copying or anything of that nature.

Comment: It's a public project. So I can't keep those convenience functions in a private dir on my HDD.

Comment: @XTF if the project doesn't already have an established location for utility routines then you could add one.

Comment: Sure, but that still requires me to keep files in multiple VCSs in sync.

Answer (score 6):

Simply calling:

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), d.data());
```

is *The way* to convert a string to the array. I don't see any advantage of wrapping this into a dedicated "utility" function.

In addition, unless the compiler optimizes it, the performance may degrade with your function: the data will be copied second time when returning the array.

Comment: That can't be used when you want to pass the array to a function directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you really only want convert *string* to an array, just use `.c_str()` (and work on `char*`). It isn't exactly `array<>` but may suit your needs.

Comment: No, it doesn't suit my needs, as that's a reference while I need a value.

Answer (score 1):

That's fine, maybe with a minor modification in C++11.

```
template<class T, size_t N, class V>
std::array<T, N> to_array(const V& v)
{
    assert(v.size() == N);
    std::array<T, N> d;
    using std::begin; using std::end; 
    std::copy( begin(v), end(v), begin(d) ); // this is the recommended way
    return d;
}
```

That way, if you remove the assertion, this function would work even if v is a raw array.

Comment: That's C++11 specific. Might be ok in this case. Are you sure it's std::begin() and not just begin()? Your code would fail for classes that do have a free begin() in their own namespace.

Comment: Should probably be `using std::begin; using std::end; std::copy(begin(v),end(v),begin(d));`

Comment: @XTF that was not the version I wrote, I didnt put the namespace, because of name lookup that should work anyway. However I believe that bames53 suggestion makes it fully generic, using std one when it s a std container and specific one when it is not (if found).

Comment: Adding the extra `using std::begin; using std::end;` makes the `to_array` truly generic. If you use `std::begin(v)` you're preventing your container `T` from overriding `begin()`. Bottom line, you need the extra line to let Koenig resolution do what it's supposed to do!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work with std::string, but if you're using a C string literal (char const *), C++20 introduces `std::to_array` for just this sort of thing:

```
std::array arr {"Hello, world!"};
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array